# how to write multiple dicom files into a folder using 'dicomwrite' command

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom, medical

using for loop, i can read all the  'k' dicom files present in the folder . After performing some operation on each slice, i need to save them into another folder .
 Someone please help me

```
names=dir(fullfile('C:\matlab\*.dcm'));
for k=1:size(names, 1)
    I(:,:,k)=dicomread(names(k).name);
    P=I(:,:,k);
    M(:,:,k) = foperation(P);
    %figure(k)
    % imshow(M(:,:,k))
    dicomwrite(M(:,:,k),'m_01.dcm')  // what and how should i change this line to save all k files 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to save all files in one command - you need to save them one by one.

I think the best solution is saving the output files in the same name of the input, but in different folder.
Save the files in the same loop your are reading them:

```
%Set output folder to C:\matlab\out
outdir = fullfile('C:\matlab\', 'out');

%Create folder if not exist
if ~exist(outdir, 'dir'), mkdir(outdir);end

for k=1:size(names, 1)
   ...

   %Store M(:,:,k) to file names(k).name in the folder C:\matlab\out
   dicomwrite(M(:,:,k), fullfile(outdir, names(k).name))
end
```